# Ant classes not picked up within maven ant run plugin execution of javac

Tags: maven, ant, javac

I have an ant project which I am trying to run via maven ant run plugin. I can successfully run the build using ant even though when using ant run plugin I get following exception while compiling sources containing imports to ant classes.

```
    [javac] xxxx/ant/src/org/apache/hadoop/hive/ant/GetVersionPref.java:21: package org.apache.tools.ant does not exist
[javac] import org.apache.tools.ant.AntClassLoader;
[javac]                            ^
[javac] xxxx/ant/src/org/apache/hadoop/hive/ant/GetVersionPref.java:22: package org.apache.tools.ant does not exist
[javac] import org.apache.tools.ant.BuildException;
```

Here is the relevant snippet of ant build file.

```
<property name="myclasspath" refid="classpath"/>
<!-- Emit the property to the ant console -->
<echo message="Classpath = ${myclasspath}"/>

<javac
 encoding="${build.encoding}"
 srcdir="${src.dir}"
 includes="**/*.java"
 destdir="${build.classes}"
 debug="${javac.debug}"
 deprecation="${javac.deprecation}"
 includeantruntime="true">
  <compilerarg line="${javac.args} ${javac.args.warnings}" />
  <classpath refid="classpath"/>
</javac>
```

The printed classpath doesn't contain ant jars in either case (running directly or via ant run plugin) so I am guessing for the first case the ant libraries are implicitly included in javac classpath somehow. Greatly appreciate any suggestion for overcoming this issue.

Comment: Which version of ant are you using when you run it from the command line?  The `antrun` plugin (version 1.7) uses ant 1.8.2 per the [pom.xml](http://svn.apache.org/viewvc/maven/plugins/tags/maven-antrun-plugin-1.7/pom.xml?revision=1190689&view=markup).

Comment: I am using ant 1.7.1 and the ant run plugin version is 1.6.

Answer (score 1):

Version 1.6 of the `antrun` plugin uses `ant-nodeps:1.8.1` per its [pom.xml](http://svn.apache.org/viewvc/maven/plugins/tags/maven-antrun-plugin-1.6/pom.xml?view=markup).  When I look in that jar I do not see the classes mentioned in the error message.

According to the [release notes in the issue tracker](http://jira.codehaus.org/secure/IssueNavigator.jspa?reset=true&mode=hide&jqlQuery=project+%3D+MANTRUN+AND+fixVersion+%3D+%221.7%22), `ant-nodeps:1.8.1` was replaced with `ant:1.8.2` in `antrun` plugin version 1.7.  (See http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/MANTRUN-162.)

Suggest updating to version 1.7 and see if it works.

```
<plugin>
  <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
  <artifactId>maven-antrun-plugin</artifactId>
  <version>1.7</version>
</plugin>
```

Comment: Okay, this is a guess; you asked for suggestions though so I'm hoping it helps.  Your ant script `javac` task has `includeAntRuntime` set to `true`. The [javac](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/javac.html) task in Ant docs says "It is usually best to set this to false so the script's behavior is not sensitive to the environment in which it is run."  But when you build with Maven, is there an Ant runtime?  It may be helpful to explicitly build the classpath in the Ant script, including the exact jars needed, so it doesn't matter how the Ant script is executed, from Ant or Maven.

Comment: I got this to work by including the ant 1.8.3 jar explicitly in the classpath as you mentioned in the comment.